# Effects of X-ray exposure on upcoming pregnancies

Tags: radiation, eggs, oogenesis

Recently we had a little fight with my girlfriend about the risks of genetic diseases for our potential baby. The thing is that she had her medical check recently and it included an X-ray examination of her chest. The doctor performing the scan warned her that she should not get pregnant for 3-6 months after the examination.

A note on the wall also read similar to this (in Chinese):

> 医生建议与X光射线接触的备孕期的女性朋友，最好在3个月后再进行怀孕，以降低胎儿畸形的风险。

Which translates roughly as:

> To reduce the risk of fetal malformations, doctors suggest that women who have had X-ray expose are better to avoid getting pregnant withing three months.

(I guess, this advice might come from the fact that [an egg develops for about 150 days](https://natural-fertility-info.com/facts-about-the-female-egg.html) before being released to the ovary?)

However, since the average radiation dose of the X-ray chest exam is reported to be around 0.1 mSv (which is about the dose of radiation you get by a couple of round-trip flights: from the US to Paris and back), I have doubts that this piece of advice has any solid scientific foundation to it. (Otherwise, I guess, airline companies should be legally bind to warn any female clients of dangers of transoceanic travel.)

Are there any studies that show effects of X-ray exams on future pregnancies? Can the risk of "fetal malformations" for any pregnancy starting shortly after an X-ray exam really be assessed?

Comment: Hmm. Why downvote?